# Access Denied Error while creating user in Active Directory c#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am trying to create a user in Active Directory through a c# windows application using the service account credentials.

When I call `userPrincipal.Save()`, I get `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied.'` error.

Can anyone help me in understanding and solving this issue? Below is my Code:

```
        PrincipalContext pricipalContext = getPrincipalContext();
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(pricipalContext);

        userPrincipal.Surname = "Sur Name";
        userPrincipal.GivenName = "First Name";
        userPrincipal.EmailAddress = "firstname.surname@test.com";
        userPrincipal.SamAccountName = "TestUser1";
        userPrincipal.VoiceTelephoneNumber = "1234567890";
        userPrincipal.EmployeeId = "R456";

        string pwdOfNewlyCreatedUser = "password123";
        userPrincipal.SetPassword(pwdOfNewlyCreatedUser);

        userPrincipal.Enabled = true;
        userPrincipal.Save();

    private static PrincipalContext getPrincipalContext()
    {
        PrincipalContext pricipalContext = null;

        string username = "serviceAccountUsername";
        string password = "serviceAccountPassword";
        string Server = "orgnization.test.com:389";
        string userdomainLdappath = "DC=test,DC=com";

        try
        {
            pricipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Server, userdomainLdappath, username, password);
            bool b = pricipalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password);                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create PrincipalContext Exception: " + e);

        }
        return pricipalContext;
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Insert(Principal p)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Save()
   at ActiveDirectoryIntegration.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Test\TestApp\ActiveDirectoryIntegration\Form1.cs:line 40
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Insert(Principal p)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Save()
   at ActiveDirectoryIntegration.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Test\TestApp\ActiveDirectoryIntegration\Form1.cs:line 40

Comment: It looks like this service account is not allowed to create users.